# Why is it necessary to register out-parameter?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm currently learning Java JDBC. Today I had a look on how stored procedures are called from within JDBC.

What I don't understand, when I have a stored procedure like for example this one:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE demo.get_count_for_department
(IN the_department VARCHAR(64), OUT the_count INT)
BEGIN
 ...
```

"the_count" is marked as an out parameter. Type is also specified. So this should all be known.

Nevertheless, I have to specify the type again

```
statement.registerOutParameter(2, Types.INTEGER);
```

I have to put the type in there again? It seems redundant to me. Why do I have to give two parameter in there at all?

```
statement = connection.prepareCall("{call get_count_for_department(?, ?)}");
```

I haven't seen this in any other programming language. You only have to take care for the in-parameter. For the out-parameter takes the function care itself.

Why is that different here?

Perhaps someone can drop me a few lines. So that I get a better idea about how those stored procedure calls work.

Comment: How is the jdbc driver to know that the stored procedure in the database has an out parameter?

Comment: Ah, okay. It's for the Java-runtime to know that the Stored Procedure will return a value of type Integer?

Comment: Yes.  This is the solution that requires the least of the actual JDBC-driver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the actual database system and JDBC driver used, it might technically not be necessary. Doing this allows a JDBC driver to execute the stored procedure without first having to query the database for metadata about the statement, and it can also be used to disambiguate between multiple stored procedures with the same name (but different parameters).

Answer (score 5):

The reason is that the sql statement is just a string as seen from java perspective.

The task of a JDBC driver is to send that string to the database and receive results.

You could read the stored procedure metadata to get information about the stored procedure you are about to call but that takes time and possibly multiple  queries to the DB.

If you want that kind of integration you go a step up from JDBC and use some kind of utilities or framework to map DB object to java ones.